# wifi config for esp32 in espidf framework of platformio

Tags: visual-studio-code, wifi, esp32, esp-idf, platformio

I have already set up the Wi-Fi part of the ESP32 using Espressif-IDE software and assigned it a specific SSID and password. I configured the SSID and password using Kconfig.projbuild.

Now, I am using another programming code in the platformio (espidf framework) where Wi-Fi is also required. However, I am facing a problem where the new SSID and password that I wrote in the programming code are not being updated. Instead, the previous SSID and password that I set before are still being displayed.

I have tried deleting all the previous configurations in the ESP by using the erase flash option in the  platformio . After doing this, the default SSID of the esp32 appears. I believe that platformio does not have access to the Wi-Fi configuration of the ESP32.
this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/timers.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_http_server.h"

#define SSID "new ssid"
#define PASS "new pasword"

static void wifi_event_handler(void *event_handler_arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data)
{
    switch (event_id)
    {
    case WIFI_EVENT_STA_START:
        printf("WiFi connecting ... \n");
        break;

    case WIFI_EVENT_STA_CONNECTED:
        printf("WiFi connected ... \n");
        break;

    case WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
        printf("WiFi lost connection ... \n");
        break;

    case IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
        printf("WiFi got IP ... \n\n");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

void wifi_connection()
{
    // 1 - Wi-Fi/LwIP Init Phase
    esp_netif_init(); // TCP/IP initiation                  s1.1
    esp_event_loop_create_default(); // event loop          s1.2
    esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta(); // WiFi station    s1.3
    wifi_init_config_t wifi_initiation = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    esp_wifi_init(&wifi_initiation); //                     s1.4
    
    // 2 - Wi-Fi Configuration Phase
    esp_event_handler_register(WIFI_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, wifi_event_handler, NULL);
    esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, wifi_event_handler, NULL);
    wifi_config_t wifi_configuration = {
        .sta = {
            .ssid = SSID,
            .password = PASS}};
    esp_wifi_set_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &wifi_configuration);

    // 3 - Wi-Fi Start Phase
    esp_wifi_start();

    // 4- Wi-Fi Connect Phase
    esp_wifi_connect();
}

static esp_err_t get_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    char *response_message = "URI Response ...";
    httpd_resp_send(req, response_message, HTTPD_RESP_USE_STRLEN);
    return ESP_OK;
}

void server_initiation()
{
    httpd_config_t server_config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
    httpd_handle_t server_handle = NULL;
    httpd_start(&server_handle, &server_config);

    httpd_uri_t uri_get = {
        .uri = "/",
        .method = HTTP_GET,
        .handler = get_handler,
        .user_ctx = NULL};
    httpd_register_uri_handler(server_handle, &uri_get);
}

void app_main(void)
{
    nvs_flash_init();   
    wifi_connection();  
    server_initiation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I have solved the problem.
I took the "Kconfig.projbuild" file from the previous programming code (Espressif-IDE) and placed it in the new project. I also made changes to the Wi-Fi initialization function, and this resolved the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/timers.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_http_server.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"


#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID      CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_SSID
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS      CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_PASSWORD
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_CHANNEL   CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_CHANNEL
#define EXAMPLE_MAX_STA_CONN       CONFIG_ESP_MAX_STA_CONN

static void wifi_event_handler(void *event_handler_arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data)
{
    switch (event_id)
    {
    case WIFI_EVENT_STA_START:
        printf("WiFi connecting ... \n");
        break;

    case WIFI_EVENT_STA_CONNECTED:
        printf("WiFi connected ... \n");
        break;

    case WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
        printf("WiFi lost connection ... \n");
        break;

    case IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
        printf("WiFi got IP ... \n\n");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

void wifi_connection()
{
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
    esp_netif_create_default_wifi_ap();

    wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,
                                                        ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID,
                                                        &wifi_event_handler,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        NULL));

    wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
        .ap = {
            .ssid = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID,
            .ssid_len = strlen(EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID),
            .channel = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_CHANNEL,
            .password = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS,
            .max_connection = EXAMPLE_MAX_STA_CONN,
            .authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK,
            .pmf_cfg = {
                    .required = false,
            },
        },
    };
    if (strlen(EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS) == 0) {
        wifi_config.ap.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_OPEN;
    }

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_AP));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_AP, &wifi_config));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());
 EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_CHANNEL);


}

static esp_err_t get_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    char *response_message = "URI Response ...";
    httpd_resp_send(req, response_message, HTTPD_RESP_USE_STRLEN);
    return ESP_OK;
}

void server_initiation()
{
    httpd_config_t server_config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
    httpd_handle_t server_handle = NULL;
    httpd_start(&server_handle, &server_config);

    httpd_uri_t uri_get = {
        .uri = "/",
        .method = HTTP_GET,
        .handler = get_handler,
        .user_ctx = NULL};
    httpd_register_uri_handler(server_handle, &uri_get);
}

void app_main(void)
{
    nvs_flash_init();   
    wifi_connection();  
    server_initiation();
}
```

And the codes inside the "Kconfig.projbuild" file:

```
menu "Example Configuration"

    config ESP_WIFI_SSID
        string "WiFi SSID"
        default "myssid"
        help
            SSID (network name) for the example to connect to.

    config ESP_WIFI_PASSWORD
        string "WiFi Password"
        default "mypassword"
        help
            WiFi password (WPA or WPA2) for the example to use.
    config ESP_WIFI_CHANNEL
        int "WiFi Channel"
        range 1 13
        default 1
        help
            WiFi channel (network channel) for the example to use.

    config ESP_MAX_STA_CONN
        int "Maximal STA connections"
        default 4
        help
            Max number of the STA connects to AP.
endmenu
```